# want to Re-direct using .htaccess to files in another folder

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

My files are inside a folder called web I want to rewrite URL as

```
 RewriteRule ^admin/mybusinessadminpannel web/index.html [NC,L]
```

I was able to re-write the URL to work as above but I want to work it like this

```
RewriteRule ^mybusinessadminpannel web/index.html [NC,L]
```

but it's sending 404 error.

and this method also ok but I can't specify the ccs and js url's there are not working when i wite the it this way

RewriteRule ^admin/mybusinessadminpannel web/index.html [NC,L]

My ccs example : 
`<link href="../web/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />`

Answer (score 0):

I found  a way

```
`RewriteBase /`



`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/`



RewriteRule ^mybusinessadminpannel web/index.html [NC,L]
```

by using this method I was able to redirect into web folder is this is a good method?